# If a promoter region of a gene is transcribed, can it get methylated?

Tags: dna-methylation

Deletion of a transcription termination site can lead to a downstream gene's promoter region being transcribed. What if that portion of the mRNA acts like an siRNA methyltransferase recruiter?